# Photoshop: Match layer sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to match the size of each layer in Photoshop? For instance, there are two layers: a background layer and a top layer. The background layer is 1280x760. The top layer has only one 84x84 brush stroke, so the size of the layer is 84x84. If the top layer was to be exported to match the same size as the background layer, it'd be scaled up. Is there a way to export a layer with all the transparent areas so that the layer is of a certain size and all elements on the layer maintain their original sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround: Take the pencil tool and insert to 2 opposite corners 1px shape, have pencil opacity=1% Of course this isn't exact, but it can be usable. Maybe you can later delete those 2 extra pixels, when you are in another application.

You do not need any extra pixels, if you in the layers panel close all but the one layer that you want to export and save the image as PNG. That PNG has size = the original image size.